# Website writing to timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, estimation, posting

we are creating a website and one of the things that we would like to do is to for the users (who are logged in to facebook) to be able to write to their timeline. Kinda like have an option (this is an example)

I would like to write this to my timeline about this political view (and then attach to their post the initial political view that they had). So if user wishes to share his responses to facebook. it would appear as this:

(this is an example)
when asked "what you think about GW Bush"
Bob said: GW sucks.

The question may and will differ, responses may be random and unpredictable.

So....how easy/difficult is it to write this app. I thought initially there is a plug in, but it seems like i need to create an app. I tried to create it, but it wants me to submit minimum of 4 screenshots. Screenshots of what? Am I looking in completely the wrong place? I have never created app for facebook, is this worth the effort or should I just hire some facebook developer, because for a person who knows how to do it and who has done it before its a two hour project?

Thank you

Comment: Screenshots of how you use Facebook. You only need to do that after you created the feature. But to add to your question. Doing what you want is not allowed. The message you publish on Facebook needs to be typed by the user. Every single character

Comment: i see button "share this deal on your timeline" all the time, how is that OK and my thing "not allowed"?

Comment: You can share a url. That is not the same as posting some predefined text.

Comment: can I share a Url and a description? does it have to be straight URL without anything, just a link? or can there be description lets say like this:  <a href="whatever">see what Bob said about blahblah</a> and btw, thank you very much for your responses and help.

Comment: Yes you can add a desciption to the url using og-tags on the page